# XDM login loop, missing or wrong session and resources files

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

I use

- Debian Wheezy/Sid with XDM
- `urxvt` as terminal as well as `i3` as window manager
- `~/.xsession` and `/.Xresources` as session and resources file, respectively.

Last night I accidentally used up all my battery, so my notebook shut down. Since then, whenever I try to login with xdm (as launched by startup), the session crashes and loops back to the login screen as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDM#XDM_loops_back_to_itself_after_login).

However, if I start XDM manually by

```
sudo xdm -session ~/.xsession
```

I can log in normally without the session crashing. Judging from the terminal layout I get, `~/.Xresources` isn't loaded and adding `-resoucres ~/.Xresources` to the line starting XDM doesn't help either.

Now, what I want is XDM to behave as before on startup, that is not to loop back to login screen after logging in, and my terminal to look as before. I believe that means I have to tell XDM to use `~/.Xresources` as well as `~/.xsession` by default.

I also tried to launch XDM as

```
sudo xdm -config .xdm-config
```

where `~/.xdm-config` is a config file I copied from `/etc/X11/xdm/xdm-config` in which I changed the values of the lines

- `DisplayManager*resources` to `/home/*myname*/.Xresources` and
- `DisplayManager*session` to `/home/*myname*/.xsession`.

As before (manually specifying) the correct session file was used, but the terminal layout remained wrong, so the correct resources file probably wasn't used.

What can I do?

Comment: By the way, I copied `.Xresources` to `.Xdefaults`, so that my terminal now looks like before, but this solution isn't as "clean" as I want it to be.

Comment: Your question is on topic and absolutely fine to stay here. If it doesn't receive enough attention, you could place a bounty on it or migrate it to [unix.SE], as you wish. If the latter is what you want, `flag` it for moderator attention to have it migrated.

Answer (score 0):

After an unsuccessful login you could look into `~/.xsession-errors`. It usually shows what went wrong.

Looking into `~/.xsession-errors` won't help though if your home directory is read-only, or full, or you ran into your quota. In this case you would get returned to the login screen quick, too, because X needs write access to your `~/.Xauthority` file.

Quota or full disk don't apply the root user (there are usually 5% of a disk space kept free for root-only usage) so that may be the reason why it worked with `sudo` but not without.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  From my research, it could be one of the following:

- the space in name bug
- no startlxdm
- missing .x-- files

#### ALWAYS BACK THESE UP FIRST & THESE FILES MAY BE IN DIFFERENT LOCATIONS BASED ON YOUR DISTRO (Mine was Void Linux)

## space in name:

1. save an extra copy of

   ```
   /usr/share/xsessions/<your desktop environment, mine was xfce>.desktop
   ```
2. open up

   ```
   /usr/share/xsessions/<your desktop environment, mine was xfce>.desktop
   ```

   as root using mousepad or other editor
3. replace all spaces (" ") with a hyphen (dash) or underscore

   - graphically, using "Search" --> "Find and Replace...." in mousepad
   - [CTRL] + H usually works
4. save changes

## no startlxdm:

1. save a copy of

   ```
   /etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf
   ```
2. open up

   ```
   /etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf
   ```

   as root using mousepad or other editor
3. after this (or similar) line:

   ```
   ## default session or desktop used when no systemwide config....
   ```

   add this line:

   ```
   session=/usr/bin/start<your desktop environment, xfce4 for me>
   ```
4. save changes

## missing .x--files:

- I have no experience here.  search around on the web.  sorry.  :/

FYI: I'm no noob to this, but no master either.  Proceed at your own risk.